# Composition of two functions: Domain and range

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got this problem in my pre-calc algebra class, and I have absolutely no idea how to answer it. The explanation didn't make any sense to me. I assume there's some sort of formula or standard way of approaching this kind of problem, but I haven't been able to find anything in my research. The answer to this specific problem isn't even that important, I just want to know *how* to solve it.
[image]

Comment: The domain of the composition $(g ∘ f )(x) = g(f(x))$ will include all the elements from the domain of $f(x)$ which have and image such that the image is included in the domain of    $g(x)$. For example, the element 3 from the domain of $f(x)$ is not included in the domain of given composition, because its image 4 is not included in the domain of $g(x)$. However, the element 4 is included in the domain of $(g ∘ f )(x)$ because its image 9 is included in the domain of $g(x)$.

Comment: The range of the composition $(g ∘ f )(x) = g(f(x))$ will include all terms from the range of $g(x)$ which have a pre-image (the element it corresponds to in the domain of $g(x)$) such that the pre-image is an element of the range of $f(x)$. For example the element {2} is a part of the range but {6} is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint for the domain $D$ of $g\circ f$*. In order to compose $g$ with $f$ we need to restrict the domain of $f$ to a subset $D$ of the domain of $f$, i.e. $\{3,4,6,7,8,9\}$, such that $f(D)$ is a subset of the domain of $g$, i.e. $\{1,5,7,8,9\}$.
For example, since $f(8)=f(3)=4\not \in \{1,5,7,8,9\}$ then $3,8\not \in D$. Moreover $f(4)=9\in \{1,5,7,8,9\}$ and therefore $4\in D$. What is $D$?

*Hint for the range of $g\circ f$* i.e. $g(f(D))$. For example, since $4\in D$ then $g(f(4))=g(9)=2\in g(f(D))$. What is $g(f(D))$?

Comment: @brier Did you find $D$ and $g(f(D))$?

Comment: Thank you! D = {4,6,7,9} and g(f(D)) = {2,7,8}

Comment: Well done, they are correct!